# Trying to create a web page to return a roman numeral in mvc when you enter an integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm totally new to coding and using MVCfor the first time, i am trying to create a webpage that when a user enters an integer into a box then hit a button it will return a roman numeral. Here is what i have so far but need help calling a method to do the conversion.
any help would be really helpful
I have included the code for model, controller and view
model:

```
public class ConvertData
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1)]
        [MaxLength(4)]
        
        public int IntergerValueToConvert { get; set; }



        public string ConvertToRoman(string numberString)
        {
            string romanValue = string.Empty;
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(numberString);
            if (number >= 1)
            {
                // Loop through each roman character from highest 
                foreach (int item in RomanDictionary().Keys)
                {
                    while (number >= item)
                    {
                        romanValue = romanValue + RomanString(item);
                        number -= item;
                    }
                }
            }
            return romanValue;
        }



        public static string RomanString(int n)
        {
            string romanString = string.Empty;
            romanString = RomanDictionary()[n].ToString();
            return romanString;
        }

        public static Dictionary<int, string> RomanDictionary()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> romanDic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            romanDic.Add(1000, "M");
            romanDic.Add(900, "CM");
            romanDic.Add(500, "D");
            romanDic.Add(400, "CD");
            romanDic.Add(100, "C");
            romanDic.Add(90, "XC");
            romanDic.Add(50, "L");
            romanDic.Add(40, "XL");
            romanDic.Add(10, "X");
            romanDic.Add(9, "IX");
            romanDic.Add(5, "V");
            romanDic.Add(4, "IV");
            romanDic.Add(1, "I");
            return romanDic;
        }
        public static bool IsValid(string input)
        {
            int value = 0;
            bool isValid = false;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
            {
                if (value <= 3000)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public class ConvertController : Controller
    {

       


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ConvertData viewModel = new ConvertData();
            

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Convert(ConvertData convertdata)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }


            return View();
        }




        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Convert2()
        {
            
               
                 
                

                return View();
        }


            
        
       

    }

}
```

View:

```
model ConverterWebApp.Models.ConvertData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Page to convert numbers </h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Numeral Converter</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IntergerValueToConvert, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IntergerValueToConvert, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interger, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@

                <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Convert2", "Convert") + "'");" />

               


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: So, what specifically is the problem? You've posted a requirement, and then posted a lot of code with no explanation of how the two are related. Are you stuck on something particular? We're not going to sit and wade through your code to work out what you might have done wrong, you need to tell us exactly what you need help with. If you have multiple issues, focus on the most important one first.

Comment: P.S. As a general point I it's very worthwhile to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: P.P.S. from a very quick scan of the code `onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Convert2", "Convert") + "'");"` looks wrong. If you're trying to submit the contents of the form, then this will not work. Your Html.BeginForm should be specifying the action that the form will be submitted to, you don't need extra javascript for that. If you've been following an MVC tutorial which explains about forms, then it should have shown that, so please pay closer attention - or if it told you do to this location.href method, then you need to find a better tutorial!

Comment: Also, your "convert" and "convert2" actions (I don't know what the difference between these is supposed to be?) don't actually do anything. Are you wanting to ask us about how to actually call a method carry out the conversion? Again, be specific about your issue.

Comment: sorry i'm very new at this, literally my first attempt, the problem is when i run it and enter a value into the text box nothing happens, and yes asking how do i actually call a method to carry out the conversion and return a roman numeral to the webpage. the one click you are referring to somebody at my work told me to add that, sorry again.

Comment: Well when the "Convert" action method is (correctly) called by submitting the form, `convertdata` is already an instance of the class which contains your method. So you could just call `string romanNumeral = convertdata.ConvertToRoman();`. N.B. Accepting `numberString` into the ConvertToRoman() method makes no sense, because the class already has its `IntergerValueToConvert` property, which (if the form is submitted correctly) will already contain the submitted data...

Comment: ...so `public string ConvertToRoman()
        {
            string romanValue = string.Empty;
            int number = this.IntergerValueToConvert;` ...etc would make more sense as the definition of the method.

Comment: thank you, you mentioned that this looked wrong onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Convert2", "Convert") + "'");" what would you advise is the best solution?

Comment: Set the target action properly in the Html.BeginForm command, as I mentioned before. To be honest it seems maybe you haven't grasped the basics yet, so I would suggest working through the Microsoft MVC tutorial so you can grasp all the concepts and practice using them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started . For BeginForm specifically, this can help you: https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/html-beginform-example-tutorial-aspnet-mvc5.php

Comment: And if you aren't yet confident about how objects work and how to call methods, then maybe even a beginner's C# tutorial (without all the MVC-specific stuff getting in the way) would be a good idea too. If you get a grounding in the core concepts and are secure in them, then you can apply that knowledge to any situation you find yourself in, and can get on with implementing features rather than getting bogged down in basic language questions.